# How to fix "Column 'Table.Column' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my syntax:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number,  
    SUM ([CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL].Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax),
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Trans_Det_Qty, 
    CRM_DB_Person.[Person DOB]
FROM
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
INNER JOIN 
    CRM_DB_Person ON CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number = CRM_DB_Person.[Loyalty Card Number]
WHERE 
    Brand = 'Jelly Bunny'
    AND Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-08-31'
GROUP BY 
    CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number
```

I get this error:

> Column 'CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Trans_Det_Qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I only wanted to group by `CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number` and not the others.
I don't want to include everything else in `GROUP BY` clause here.

What is the solution to this?

Thank you for all answers.

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: I think here also required to sum up `CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Trans_Det_Qty`

Comment: Remove all columns from the `SELECT`, except for the columns in `GROUP BY` and the ones that are arguments to aggregation functions.

Answer (score 0):

included `non aggregated columns` during `group by`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number 
    , SUM ([CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL].Trans_Det_Amt_ex_Tax)
    , CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Trans_Det_Qty
    , CRM_DB_Person.[Person DOB]
FROM CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL
INNER JOIN CRM_DB_PersonON CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number = CRM_DB_Person.[Loyalty Card Number]
WHERE Brand = 'Jelly Bunny'
    AND Trans_Hdr_Sale_Date between '2019-01-01'AND '2019-08-31'
GROUP BY CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Loyalty_Number, CRM_POWERBI_RETAIL.Trans_Det_Qty, CRM_DB_Person.[Person DOB]
```